# argument of type 'Mesh *' is incompatible with parameter of type 'Mesh *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, pointers, mesh

This error is baffling me as I know I've managed to pass a pointer to an object to a function of another class before but now it just doesn't want to work.

```
//source.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

// OPENGL Dependencies
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>

// VBO Indexer
#include "vboindexer.hpp"

// My classes
#include "controls.h"
#include "MyMeshClass.h"

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

int width = WIDTH;
int height = HEIGHT;


controls* Controls; // pointer to controls object
Mesh* MyMesh;

void Display() {
    GLuint pickingProgramID, gvertexbuffer;

    if (true) { 
        Controls->myPicking( MyMesh, pickingProgramID, 
                             gvertexbuffer);
    }
}
void InitMesh() {
    //loads object
    MyMesh = new Mesh();
}

void InitializeResources() {
    InitMesh();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // GLUT initialization.
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("Codebase 1, 3.3+ Edition");

    glewInit();
    Controls = new controls(height, width);

    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    InitializeResources();

    // Enter GLUT loop.
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;

}
```

---

```
//controls.h
#pragma once
#ifndef CONTROLS_H
#define CONTROLS_H
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>

#include "MyMeshClass.h"

class controls {
private:

protected:
    static controls *instance;
public:
    controls();

    controls( int nheight, int nwidth );


    void myPicking( Mesh* MyMesh,
                          GLuint pickingProgramID,  
                          GLuint gvertexbuffer );

};

#endif
```

---

```
//Controls.cpp

#include "controls.h"

controls *controls::instance = NULL;

controls::controls() {

}

controls::controls( int nheight, int nwidth ) {

}


void controls::myPicking( Mesh* MyMesh,
                            GLuint pickingProgramID,    
                          GLuint gvertexbuffer ) 
{


}
```

---

```
// MyMeshClass.h
#pragma once

class Mesh { 
private:

public:

};
```

As you can see I define my pointer, its substantiated with 'new' in another function that executes before it gets to Display(), and I pass it to the Controls class as an argument in the myPicking function but I get the above error that just confuses me.

Edit:

Alright so to also clarify, its a syntax/intellisense error, it isn't form compilation but appears in the editor at the function all where I try to pass it to the myPicking(...) function.

Comment: That error message does not make sense. Perhaps you could simplify your code to make it possible to post the it here.

Comment: Does declaration of Mesh in an unnamed namespace ?

Comment: This is the simplified code, I'm not sure how I could simplify it further, you're right it doesn't make sense but that's exactly the error and these are the minimum bits of code that demonstrate it. I have a pointer/pointer object variable, I am trying to pass it to a function, it gives me that error.

I'm not sure what you mean Jarod.

Comment: Do you use `namespace` ? where and how do you define `Mesh` ? Which compiler do you use ? Give enough info to help us to help you.

Comment: "Mesh" is defined in MeshClass.h I do not use namespace and I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This is _not_ the simplified code. You don't even show a call site, and there's no `int main`. None of the identifiers are defined. http://sscce.org

Comment: Because main is only used to register callbacks as its opengl code, everything done is done in Display() except for where MyMesh is initialized in InitResources(), I really don't think its helpful to have shown anything else but I put it up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have found the problem, it was a stealth circular dependency issue, partly caused by trusting intellisense error's to also be compilation errors.

Once I put my Mesh class in #ifndef -> #endif and compiled the error went away.

As I was calling Controls.h first, which calls my mesh class, and then called it again, causing a redefinition error but I could only see this at compilation time.

It seems to be solved now.

Comment: Given that your question shows that you're already using `#pragma once`, this shouldn't make any difference, assuming the compiler you're using supports `#pragma once`. You've tagged the question [tag:visual-studio-2010], and [the documentation shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that it is supported in that. (That's not to say that it isn't good that you're no longer affected by whatever problem you're having, of course.)

Comment: The code up there isn't actually my *actual* code, its a 'simplified' version of my code, I put in pragma once so it would stop complaining about an unrelated error. What I was doing was adding a new file to my project and copying and pasting in segments from my code and then copying that to here, such as an empty mesh class (the actual class is 500 lines).